# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'. pobleme

Tags: java, android

i have this probleme with android studio 3 ,

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.
>
> > java.io.IOException: Can't write [C:\Users\karam\Desktop\android\app\build\intermediates\multi-dex\debug\componentClasses.jar]
> >     (Can't read
> >     [C:\Users\karam.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-compat-25.2.0.aar\c04eaa88d08211c4eca04dcb2a06098c\jars\classes.jar(;;;;;;**.class)]
> >     (Duplicate zip entry
> >     [classes.jar:android/support/v4/view/ViewCompat.class]))

and this is the build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.boy.adventure"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 25
        multiDexEnabled true

        ndk {
            moduleName "player_shared"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }


    }
    sourceSets.main {
        jni.srcDirs = []// <-- disable automatic ndk-build call
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services:+') { exclude module: 'support-v4' }
    compile files('libs/dagger-1.2.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/javax.inject-1.jar')
    compile files('libs/nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/support-v4-19.0.1.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

Comment: The same here. have you found a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Please don't use dynamic versions for your dependencies! In our case this caused the problem (a library was using dynamic version for support libraries and caused conflict with our defined version)
http://blog.danlew.net/2015/09/09/dont-use-dynamic-versions-for-your-dependencies/